# Filter data frame based on index value in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` with thousands of rows, and a sample is this:

```
    Index           A   B   C   D   E   F               
    EX-A.1.A.B-1A  18   7   2   2   9   8       
    EX-A.1.A.B-1C   0   0   0   0   0   0       
    EX-A.1.A.B-4A   6   4   8   6   1   1   
    EX-A.1.A.B-4C   0   0   0   0   0   0   
    EX-A.1.A.B-4F   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I also have a list `my_list = ["EX-A.1.A.B-1A","EX-A.1.A.B-4A","EX-A.1.A.B-4F"]`

and I want to filter the `df` based on this list, therefore I want to keep the rows for which the index value is in the list `my_list`.

I tried this in order to create a new filtered df: `Filter_df = df[df.index in my_list]` and I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas on how I could do this? Thanks

Comment: Use `Filter_df = df.loc[my_list]`

Comment: Or this: 
    `Filter_df  = df.loc[ df.index.intersection(my_list) ]`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To check if row indices are in `my_list`:

```
    Filter_df = df[df.index.isin(my_list)]
```

Comment: it does not return unique index. what could be done to return the same number of rows as the my_list?

Comment: I think what you need is `drop_duplicates`. Check here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html